# How Many Unix Groups Can A User Be A Member Of?

Tags: linux, unix

We've recently run into a situation at a group-happy site where some group memberships are not being picked up.  I seem to remember that there is an upper limit to the number of groups that a user can be a member of.

While I am specifically interested in modern Linux systems, I also remember that for some older versions of some OSs that number is lower?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The specific answer seems to be:

- up to 32 on a modern linux
- [except if you are accessing a file over nfs, in which case it is 16](http://www.insectnation.org/articles/2007/05/08/linux-nfs-16-group-limit/)

...which explains our problem, we've recently crossed the 16-group boundary for some users.

Comment: The 16 groups per user limit is part of the sunRPC mechanism used for NFS (<4?). See RFC1057 "9.2 UNIX Authentication"

Comment: link to nfs group limit is broken

Comment: While this answer was correct when written, it's not quite true for any modern kernel. It's been 64 for over a decade now.

Answer (score 10):

For Linux Kernel 2.6.3 and above the limit is [64k groups](http://www.j3e.de/ngroups.html) per user.

If you are using NFSv4 the limit is [higher than 16](http://nfsworld.blogspot.de/2005/03/whats-deal-on-16-group-id-limitation.html), too. (not sure about exact numbers here)

Answer (score 4):

Look for NGROUPS_MAX in limits.h to find the value on your system.

I *think* this is a tunable parameter in a modern Linux kernel.   (Used to be 16 on Solaris, I don't know if they have fixed that yet.)

Comment: Just checked a Solaris 11 server, not it is not fixed there - still 16 :-(

Comment: You can also use `getconf NGROUPS_MAX` to receive this value from a shell.

Answer (score 2):

You can overcome the 16 group limit for NFS on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora by updating the following setting in /etc/sysconfig/nfs:

```
RPCMOUNTDOPTS="--manage-gids"
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this: [sysconf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    long max_group = 0;
    max_group = sysconf(_SC_NGROUPS_MAX);
    printf("Max group : %ld\n", max_group);
    return 0;
}
```

in the shell :

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors -o maxgroup maxgroup.c
```

Comment: Can you explain why someone needs to compile a C program to get these values?

Comment: Because it's system-specific and subject to change?

Answer (score -2):

See [Above](https://superuser.com/a/1566938/1463758) .
You can get from sysconf the number of groups.
You can use simple python one-line to get the value.

```
python -c 'import os; print(hex(os.sysconf("SC_NGROUPS_MAX")))'
```

Comment: A bit more detail would improve the answer

Comment: All the other data is written above, just gave a way to do the same without compile :)

Comment: All answers must be complete. This is not a forum. Any given answer could be deleted and so each answer must be complete in and of itself, otherwise it belongs as a comment.