# Number of groups for unix user limit change

Tags: linux, unix, user-accounts

In continuation of the question [How Many Unix Groups Can A User Be A Member Of?](https://superuser.com/questions/26599/how-many-unix-groups-can-a-user-be-a-member-of): can I somehow change this limit?

Comment: I am not aware how to change the limit (unless you want to fiddle with kernel code). But the limits have changed since 2.6.3, see my answer in your linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the only way known to me is to change the kernel code.

You find the limit inside [limits.h](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux-bk+v2.6.10/include/linux/limits.h#L6).

Since there have been quite some updates to the kernel it might be possible to decrease this limit with some configuration file, eg with the help of PAM.

Answer (score 0):

In Solaris it can be changed in `/etc/system` (or `/etc/system.d/<somefile>` in version 11.2 or later)

```
set ngroups_max = <number>
```

Where number is between 16 and 1024; a reboot is needed if it is changed.